# How to access the content of the log file after using Pyomo to call a solver in NEOS server?

Tags: using, logfile, pyomo, neos-server

I am using Pyomo to run BONMIN solver from the NEOS server. However, it returns a simple log file without any useful information such as the number of iterations. Can you let me know what I should do to retrieve the full log file?
The code in Pyomo is as follows:

```
opt_prob = pyomo.opt.SolverFactory(bonmin, solver_io = minlp)
opt_prob.options['max_iter']    = self.max_iter
opt_prob.options['tol']         = self.tol
solver_manager = pyomo.opt.SolverManagerFactory('neos')
results = solver_manager.solve(self.model, keepfiles=True, tee=True, opt=opt_prob)
```

The content of the log file right now is as follows:
`Job 6915952 dispatched
password: lBdrJjXS
---------- Begin Solver Output -----------
Condor submit: 'neos.submit'
Condor submit: 'watchdog.submit'
Job submitted to NEOS HTCondor pool.`

Comment: This is my problem too.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this question still needs answering, but would it help to save the logfile externally?

So add:

```
results = solver_manager.solve(self.model, keepfiles=True, tee=True, opt=opt_prob, logfile = "name.csv")
```